# Getting error while using 'ui.bootstrap' and '720kb.datepicker' module in same Angular.js application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am getting the following error while using `ui.bootstrap`and `720kb.datepicker` module at a time in one application in Angular.js.

```
Error: [$compile:multidir] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/$compile/multidir?p0=datepicker&p1=&p2=da…-prev%3D%22%3Ci%20class%3D%26quot%3Bfa%20fa-arrow-circle-left%26quot%3B%3E
    at Error (native)
    at http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:6:416
    at Q (http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:69:353)
    at D (http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:62:492)
    at http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:68:182
    at http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:118:334
    at n.$eval (http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:132:452)
    at n.$digest (http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:129:463)
    at n.$apply (http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:133:236)
    at g (http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:87:376)
```

When i am removing `ui.bootstrap` module this error is not coming but i strongly need also `ui.bootstrap` module.I am explaining my code below.

```
<datepicker date-format="dd-MM-y" button-prev='<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i>' button-next='<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>'> 
                                <input type="text" name="birthdate" class="form-control" ng-model="date" placeholder="Add date" />
                                </datepicker>
```

Please help me to resolve this error by using the both module.

Answer (score 1):

Update `ui.bootstrap` module to a version **above 0.14.0**. The team behind the module prefixed the name of the directives with `uib-` to avoid such collisions.

Comment: @ Michael : i also fixed this changing <datepicker> to <div class="datepicker"></div>.

Comment: Datepicker directive from `720kb.datepicker` is restricted to `'EAC'`, whereas datepicker from `ui.boostrap` is restricted to `'EA'`. Thus using datepicker directive as a class as you did fixes the *multidir* error, since it leads to only one directive. But I find the namespacing of `ui.bootstrap` directives with `uib-` a better solution, though I admit it is probably more costly to you. I'd rather avoid using directives as a class. Think of other developers joining the project.

Comment: Additionally, we've removed the deprecated directives (read:  the non-prefixed ones) in `master` for the 1.0 release, so if you want to upgrade from 0.14.x to 1.0 - you **will** need to fix them or none of your Angular UI Bootstrap directives will work.